# SQL Super Search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Does anyone have a good method for searching an entire database for a given value?
I have a specific string I'm looking for, it's in TableA, and it's also a FK to some other table, TableB, except I don't know which table/column that is.

Assuming there's a jillion tables and I don't want to look through them all, and maybe will have to do this in several different cases, what would be the best way?

Since I didn't want a Code-SQL bridge, my only all-SQL idea was:

```
select tablename and column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

...then use a cursor to flip through all the columns, and for all the datatypes of nvarchar I would execute dynamic SQL like:

```
SELECT * from @table where @column =  @myvalue
```

Needless to say, this is slow AND a memory hog.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Does it really matter that its 'slow'.  As long as it is faster than searching manually you win.  Unless this is a process in your application for one reason or another.  In which case you should really look into re designing your solution.

Comment: true. this is a tool used in dev, no in production, and it is WAY faster than searching manually. I was just curious as to a better way because i'm not really a SQL expert and I figured there was a more direct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of links talking about how to do this:

- http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2
- http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Both of them use the approach you were hoping to avoid. Refine them so that they only searched columns that were foreign keys should improve their performance by eliminating the searching of unnecessary tables.

Comment: This is the way I ended up going. Also, a +1 for making me feel better about the way I was already doing it :)

Answer (score 6):

Dump the database and grep?

I guess a more focused question might be: if you don't know how the schema works, what are you going to do with the answer you get anyway?

Comment: +1 for _if you don't know how the schema works, what are you going to do with the answer you get anyway?_

Comment: well, its a FK. I just need to build a link between two tables so I can store associated data. The data itself isn't important right now, just as long as I link it so it's captured. How does one go about dumping the whole DB to text?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I wrote several years ago:
http://www.users.drew.edu/skass/sql/SearchAllTables.sql.txt

Comment: that's actually what I had more or less. It's really slow on this huge db, and a memory hog, but it does the job.

Comment: hi, is there a way to only search specific columns across a couple of tables.

Comment: In the example's first two SELECT queries, you could add conditions to the WHERE clause to restrict the result to particular table names and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Just make SP that searches in all relevant columns using OR.

Why don't you know which columns to search on?

If the list of columns is ever-shifting, then you just need to make sure that whatever process results in changing the schema would result in the change in this stored procedure.

If the list of the columns is just too dang big for you to type up inot the SP, use some elementary perl/grep/whatnot to do it in 1 line, e.g for SYBASE.

```
my_dump_table_schema.pl|egrep "( CHAR| VARCHAR)"|awk '{$1}'|tr "\012" " "|perl -pe '{s/ / = \@SEARCH_VALUE OR /g}'; echo ' = @SEARCH_VALUE'
```

The last echo is needed to add the value to last column

Answer (score 0):

to dump your data, read up on the [bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)